# What is the correct way to use active storage with apartment gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have Organization model which is excluded from apartment gem with one attached image, I am able to upload the image to the correct tenant but after generating image URL I get error in custom elevator of apartment gem. I'm pretty sure that the URL generation is correct. It seems like multi-tenancy with active storage gem works a bit differently. The `ActiveStorage::Blob and ActiveStorage::Attachment` are not excluded from apartment